# PostgreSQL - Multiple constraints

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I want to add several `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` to a PostgreSQL 13 table. In natural language logic is : if a field contain a defined value, an other field must be filled. I have several scenarios to combine. When I add just one constraint it's ok, but when I want to accumulate them, `CONSTRAINTS` aren't respected and row can't be inserted.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo_table
(
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('demo_table_id_seq'::regclass),        
    thematic character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    field_a character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    field_b character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    CONSTRAINT demo_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT field_a_check CHECK (thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text AND field_a IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT field_b_check CHECK (thematic::text ~~ 'B'::text AND field_b IS NOT NULL)
)
```

My expected logic is : when `thematic` like '`A`', `field_a` can't be `NULL` or when `thematic` like '`B`' `field_b` can't be `NULL`. With this settings I can't add rows because my `CONSTRAINTS` definitions never check both conditions (`field_a IS NOT NULL and field_b IS NOT NULL`).

I tried to define an unique `CONSTRAINT` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551572/sql-check-constraint-with-multiple-conditions), but `CHECK CONSTRAINT` isn't respected either because parenthesis who isolate conditions aren't saved in the definition.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo_table
(
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('demo_table_id_seq'::regclass),        
    thematic character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    field_a character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    field_b character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",        
    CONSTRAINT demo_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT field_a_b_check CHECK (thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text AND field_a IS NOT NULL OR thematic::text ~~ 'B'::text AND field_b IS NOT NULL)
)
```

How to combine multiple `CONSTRAINTS` like `(IF ... ) OR (IF ... ) OR (IF ...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your constraints are not full.
For example:

```
CONSTRAINT field_a_check CHECK (thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text AND field_a IS NOT NULL),
```

The constraint says "the record is ok if `thematic` contains 'A' and `field_a` is not empty". That means the record is not OK otherwise (if it does not contain 'A'). If you appended your checks with "OK otherwise" you could have several of them - no problem:

```
CONSTRAINT field_a_check CHECK (thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text AND field_a IS NOT NULL OR NOT thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text)
```

As to why the parenthesis are removed - it's because they are not needed. The AND operator has priority over OR, so the expressions are the same with or without parenthesis.

You are welcome to check the solution at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ed5ec01e27d5bd328d915887bd12c70)

Comment: Ok with your example and logic but when I execute this I still have a violation of `CHECK CONSTRAINT` when I try to `INSERT` `thematic = 'A'` and something in `field_a`.

Comment: What error message do you get? See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ed5ec01e27d5bd328d915887bd12c70  `insert into demo_table(thematic, field_a) VALUES ('A', 'field_a');` suceeds

Comment: With your `CONSTRAINT` definition and this `INSERT` I have this message ` `ERROR: new row for relation "demo_table" violates check constraint "field_a_check" DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3a9cad02-5733-4abd-8998-a1052e6c353e, 32, A, null)`

Comment: So the constraint works? You try to insert a record with thematic = A and field_a =NULL and get a constraint violation. What is interesting the record '(3a9cad02-5733-4abd-8998-a1052e6c353e, 32, A, null)' does not contain a value for field_b - did you remove it ?

Comment: Something strange : with same version of `PostgreSQL`, table definition, `CONTRAINT` and `INSERT` it doesn't work on my side but it's ok on dbfiddle. I'm looking for possible differences and  erros and give a feedback.

Comment: I understand the difference, my `CONSTRAINT` definition wasn't exactly the same as yours, last part is important `... OR NOT thematic::text ~~ 'A'::text`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
alter table table_1 
add constraint ck_only_one check ((col1 is null and col2 is not null) or (col2 is null and col1 is not null));
```

Separation with parenthesis is to be given for better segregation.

Comment: Parenthesis are the problem : if I execute this, they aren't saved when I check `CONSTRAINT` properties. Make a try, you will see.